# How to simultaneously upload and download file

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to write a small Tornado server that lets users upload files using a HTML `form`, then give the link to someone else who then will simultaneously download the file while it is being uploaded.

For now the idea was that `data` would be some sort of `Iterator` that is created by the upload and then consumed by the download, however currently the entire file is being written into `data`.

I found a few people talking about chunked file uploads with Tornado, however couldn't find any reference pages for it.

```
import os
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

settings = {'debug': True} 

data = None

# assumes an <input type="file" name="file" />
class ShareHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, uri):
        data = self.request.files['file'][0]['body']

class FetchHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, uri):
        for line in data:
            self.write(line)

handlers = [
    (r'/share/(.*)', ShareHandler),
    (r'/fetch/(.*)', FetchHandler),
]

application = tornado.web.Application(handlers, **settings)
application.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tornado doesn't support streaming uploads. This is one of the most commonly asked questions about it. =) The maintainer is actively implementing the feature, watch here:

https://github.com/facebook/tornado/pull/1021